# C# How to call the inner list constructor inorder to define capacity

Tags: c#, constructor, nested-lists, list-initialization

I would like to access the inner list constructor inorder to define capacity, how could i achieve this?
This is what i have: this will initialize the outer list to 20 elements.

```
public List<List<(int x, int y)>> coordinatesForHorizontalShips = new List<List<(int x, int y)>>(20);
```

From microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0
List(Int32)
Initializes a new instance of the List class that is empty and has the specified initial capacity.

C#

```
Copy
public List (int capacity);
Parameters
capacity
Int32
The number of elements that the new list can initially store.
```

Comment: Add 20 lists to the outer list, each of those inner lists will have to be constructed with a capacity of 20? You could do: `= Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(_ => new List<(int x, int y)>(20)).ToList()`

Comment: Note that if the capacity is *fixed* (as in, you don't intend to ever add anything but exactly 20 items to inner and outer lists), a multidimensional array may be a more obvious choice (`(int x, int y)[,] coords = new (int x, int y)[20, 20]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to initialize `20` outer lists with each having 1_000 capacity:

```
public List<List<(int x, int y)>> coordinatesForHorizontalShips =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(x => new List<(int x, int y)>(1000)).ToList();
```